# How to open a pdf from a link inside a docbook generated pdf into new pdf viewer window

Tags: xslt, docbook, docbook-xsl

In my docbook user guide project I have a link to a small 2 page quickstart in pdf format. After I generate and open the user guide pdf and then click on link to quickstart pdf, the quickstart replaces user guide in acrobat reader. Is it possible for quickstart to open in separate pdf viewer. My research indicates no. However, it is possible to open the pdf to a specific page, but not what I want.
`xlink:href="qs.pdf#page=3"`

Comment: I discovered that if a user presses the control key and then clicks on pdf link the second pdf file opens in a new acrobat reader window. Is it possible to emulate this key press action either in docbook or xslt template?

Comment: Crazy idea - xsl template that inserts javascript that simulates control key press when link is selected. Has anyone tried this.